Are there Church Fathers who adhered to Consubstantiation? If so, which ones and what are the citations?
I am studying the belief of the Church Fathers regarding the Eucharist. In this study, I have seen that some fathers adopted Transmutation (Orthodox Catholic View) and others Sacramental Union (Lutheran View). But, are there Church Fathers who adhered to Consubstantiation? If so, which ones and what are the citations?
